# After deleteRows used, becomeFirstResponer() doesn't give focus to textField

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfielddelegate, becomefirstresponder

After any row is deleted by `deleteRows(at:with:)` from my Table View, I cannot get textfield in a reusable custom cell to get focus by `becomeFirstResponder()` (which is called after `insertRows(at:with:)` is called). `becomeFirstResponder()` is always called within `cellForRow(at:)`.

This problem always starts occuring after a row is deleted from the table view by `deleteRows(at:with:)`. Before any row is deleted there is no problem, `becomeFirstResponder()` can give focus to the textfield as intended.

I made some tests to understand why this problem occurs after a row is deleted... My tests showed an interesting difference:

**Case 1**: After any row is deleted (i.e. while `becomeFirstResponder()` returns false), `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` is called ***BEFORE*** `cellForRow(at:)` returns. `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` is never called.

**Case 2**: On the other hand, before any row is deleted (i.e. while `becomeFirstResponder()` returns true), `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)` is called ***AFTER*** `cellForRow(at:)` returns. `textFieldDidBeginEditing(_:)` is called immediately after `textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_:)`, as expected.

The problem might be related to this difference, but I couldn't solve this mystery after trying & researching for many hours.

In a [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41458120/textfieldshouldbeginediting-called-textfielddidbeginediting-not-called), it is suggested not to reload tableView from within `textFieldDidEndEditing()`. In my case, `deleteRows(at:with:)` method are sometimes called from within `textFieldDidEndEditing()` and sometimes called from `tableView(_:commit:forRowAt:)` (i.e. by swiping to left). So this does not explain my problem. Another related Q&A might be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33701832/how-to-update-a-uitableview-so-that-uitextfield-in-a-cell-wont-lose-focus).

getFocus() in CustomCell's class, called from `cellForRow(at:)` in TableViewController:

```
func getFocus() {
    if let itemTextField = itemTextField {
        itemTextField.delegate = self
        itemTextField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        itemTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

`cellForRow(at:)`:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.setCell(item: item)
    cell.delegate = self

    if insertingRow == true {
        if isTempItem(item: item, indexPath: indexPath) {
                cell.getFocus()
        } else {
            print("isTempItem returned false, no need to give focus.")
        }
    }

    return cell     
}
```

Comment: Don't call `getFocus` in `cellForRowAt`. The cell may not even be added to the table view yet.

Comment: It seemed to me that is the only place where I can get access to the cell. Where else can I call it? Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't call `getFocus` in `cellForRowAt`, Insteed of when you insert new row, You can scroll to new row and call `getFocus` in `willDisplayCell`.

Hope to help you.

Comment: This solved my problem. In fact I tried to use willDisplayCell but couldn't figure out how to use a custom cell with that method. With a little research I figured that out too. Thank you!